# Reading input from DJ Decks (pioneer)

Tags: c#, keyboard, keymapping

I've been looking online for a tool to remap inputs from my pioneer DJ decks (pioneer ddj-200), but there doesn't seem to be a tool online that allows this. I've tried the programs that allow it from xBox controller inputs (xmap, JoyToKey) but they don't work; so decided to make my own.

I'm most familiar reading keys with C# so I'm attempting with this, but I have no idea where to start. I can read keys and display on screen, but they KeyDown function doesn't respond to inputs from my decks.

I've looked online for any sort of guidance but it seems pretty closed off as an area. Does anyone know how I could even check what the decks are inputting?

Thanks

Comment: Do they have proprietary drivers? Do they emulate an input device (like mouse/keyboard?) ... I guess they connect via USB?

Comment: They do connect via USB; the ones I have are just plug and play. In device manager they appear as a human interface device named USB Input Device.

Comment: Most likely you can talk to it using [MIDI](https://github.com/dan-giddins/mixxx-ddj-200-mapping/blob/master/Pioneer-DDJ-200-scripts.js).  This is otherwise too broad and off-topic.  Seems like some reverse-engineering may be required unless they document any of their proprietary commands.

Comment: Thanks for the link anyway.